# Designing an RPG for class, stuck with my loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So first of all apologies for bad code style, this is my first big project(a final for my python class). I'm stuck on the loop setup I need to move from the "main menu" displaymenu function to the movemenu function, as it runs right now when selecting the choice A from displaymenu nothing happens, the choice b and c work just fine. My guess is its a problem with how I designed the loops, and breaking/moving from one loop to another.

As far as the actual movement goes, I took a pretty good stab at it, but making the menus work is critical to even being able to test the movement, so thats where I am in that regard.

Any input or constructive criticism is very appreciated. Thank you

```
#map movement functions---------------------------------------------------------


def mapFunc(x,y):
    if x == 0:
        if y == 0:
            print("Sh*ts Swampy yo")
        elif y == 1:
            print("Sh*ts Sandy broski")
        elif y == 2:
            print("trees everywhere bro")
        else:
            print("how the f**k did you get here")
    elif x == 1:
        if y == 0:
            print("Sh*ts Swampy yo")
        elif y == 1:
            print("Sh**s Sandy broski")
        elif y == 2:
            print("trees everywhere bro")
        else:
            print("how the f**k did you get here")
    elif x == 2:
        if y == 0:
            print("S**s Swampy yo")
        elif y == 1:
            print("Sh*s Sandy broski")
        elif y == 2:
            print("trees everywhere bruh")
        else:
            print("how the f**k did you get here")






def displayMenu():
    choice = None
    choice = input("""



Choose from the following options:

A.)Map Movement

B.) Display Inventory and Stats

C.) Configure Power Treads
""").upper()

    if choice == 'A':
        moveMenu()
        completed = True
    elif choice == 'B':
        displayStats(player)
    elif choice == 'C':
        askPowerTread()
    else:
        choice not in ['A','B','C']
        print("Invalid choice.")


def moveMenu():
    choice = None
    validMapMovement = False
    #while choice not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'):
    while not validMapMovement:
        choice = input
        ("""
        Choose a direction:

    A.) North
    B.) South
    C.) East
    D.) West
    """).upper()

    if choice == 'A':
    if playerY (+1) >= 0:
            playerY -= 1
            mapFunc(playerX, playerY)
            validMapMovement = True
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")
    elif choice == 'B':
        if playerY +1 <= 2: 
            playerY += 1
            mapFunc(playerX, playerY)
            validMapMovement = True
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")
    elif choice == 'C':
        if playerX +1 <= 2: 
            playerX += 1
            mapFunc(playerX, playerY)
            validMapMovement = True
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")
    elif choice == 'D':
        if playerY -1 >= 0:
            playerX -= 1
            mapFunc(playerX, playerY)
            validMapMovement = True
    else:
         print("Invalid Choice")
    else:
        choice not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
        print("Invalid Choice") 
        roll()
```

then the file with my main in it

```
#ExampleQuest, v5.5
from ExampleQuestFunctions import *
import random #rolls
import time   #sleep
                                #       Introduction        #


#Main Loop()---------------------------------------------------------------------------
player = ["",20,5,10,3,7,0]
playerInventory = []
playerX = 0
playerY = 0

def mapPhase():    
    completed = False
    while not completed:
        displayMenu()   


#Battle Loop()---------------------
def battlePhase():

#Instance Variables 
playerTurn = True
completed = False

playAgain = True
while playAgain:
    #Create the enemy pool, and generate a random enemy
    pool = createEnemyPool()
    enemy = random.choice(pool)

    #Start the battle
    player = battle(player, enemy, playerTurn)

    #Continue Adventure
    if getString("Would you like to continue your adventure?").upper() not in    ['Y','YES']:
        playAgain = False
    else:
        playAgain = False
    inventoryUpdate()



#-----------------------    
def main():
    mapPhase()

#Run it!
main()
```

Comment: Are you sure the indentation in your code is correct? e.g. def main(): has the same indentation as mapPhase().

Comment: my indentation is fine, im writing this in IDLE so it throws syntax errors instantly if its off. All maphase() is right now is a boolean

   my indentation might look funky in here because of the formatting requirements to post

Comment: I'm sure your teacher will be very pleased with your language :)

Comment: Python is a language where indentation is important. I doubt anyone can help you properly, if they cannot read the code correctly. Please format this exactly how you see it in IDLE.

Comment: hahaha thats totally coming out, i want to ensure the map works before i spend time talking about the sunset kissed moors of ExampleQuest lol

Comment: and @ArtjomB. i just lined up the rest, not terribly familiar with the formatting that the site requires to post code, so that was my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this is how I would do it, assuming I understand your question ... then you just format a menulist for each menu and it takes care of pretty much everything

```
def get_player_choice(choices):
    labels,actions = zip(*choices)
    choice_actions = dict(enumerate(actions,1))
    for choice_id,label in enumerate(labels,1):
        print "%d. %s"%(choice_id,label)
    while True:
        result = raw_input("Select Option:")
        try:
            return choice_actions[int(result)]
        except TypeError:
            print "ERROR: Please enter a number choice!"
        except KeyError:
            print "ERROR: Unknown Choice!"

def LookAround():
     print "You See Something!"
def Quit():
     print sys.exit       

menu_a = [
("Look Around",LookAround),
("Quit!",Quit)
       ]
fn = get_player_choice(menu_a)
fn()
```

Comment: I'll be happy to try and implement that, some of your syntax is outside of my comfort zone of novicehood but i can understand the general flow of it